# NSPanel removed in Xcode 8?

Tags: macos, cocoa, storyboard, xib, nspanel

In the past I can find Panel available in Interface Builder's Library, but in Xcode 8, I searched the whole library in storyboard editor, no Panel available. Has Apple just removed `NSPanel` or I got something wrong?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Assuming you want to add a second window (as a panel) to your storyboard, add a new `window controller`.  Then select its `window` and change its class to `NSPanel`.  In the attributes inspector you will find that your panel can then be changed to `regular`, `utility` or `HUD`.

*For Cocoa apps, I find that Nibs/Xibs are sometimes easier to work with than storyboards.*